# Problems installing Dash (plotly)

Tags: pip, plotly, conda

When trying to install the Dash package using both pip and conda, I am getting an error saying that the package cannot be found. All other packages install fine with pip

The Dash Package:
https://plot.ly/dash/getting-started

```
pip install dash==0.18.3
```

> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
>       wb.build(autobuilding=True)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
>       self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
>       ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
>       require_hashes
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
>       self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
>       all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
>       for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
>       page = self._get_page(location)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, in _get_page
>       return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, in get_page
>       inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
>     File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, in **init**
>       namespaceHTMLElements=False,
>   TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'

```
conda install dash==0.18.3
```

> Fetching package metadata .............
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
>
> - dash ==0.18.3
>
> We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
>
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch

Comment: I am getting this also on a windows machine with Anaconda. I am tempted to go to Bokeh as this doesn't bode well on the package management front.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it via:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash
```

More details on can be found here:
[Anaconda Dash](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dash)